# How to use inputs within the class?

Tags: python, class

I am new to python and object language. I am learning class in python now. but the code below confused me.

```
class math:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        math.add = self.a+self.b

    def sum(self):
        math.sum = self.a+self.b

s= math(2,1)
x = math.add
y = math.sum
```

the results look not right. x is 3 but y is not 3. where is my problem?

thanks

Comment: You're messing _everything_ up.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing what you wanted to do was this.

```
class math:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.add = self.a+self.b

    def sum(self):
        return self.a+self.b

s= math(2,1)
x = s.add
y = s.sum()

print(x)
print(y)
```

The errors were as follows

1. You were not calling your instance of `math`. As these are instance methods, they must reference an instance  `x = math.add` should be `x = s.add`.
2. You created a method `sum` but did not call it `y = s.sum` simply creates a reference to the function and does not call it, instead you should use `y = s.sum()`
3. Your function `sum` doesn't return anything, so assigning a value to its return value will yield a value of None. To resolve this return a value from sum i.e. `return self.a + self.b`.

`self.add` is also quite strange, as it named like a function, but its actually a value, this will not be expected by others looking at your code. A better name for it might be total or remove it since it provides the same functionality as `sum`.